# How to show the image of related product in Magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: php, image, magento, product

Can you suggest a php code in order to show the **image of a related product**

I am using this code in  view.phtml

```
<?php $related_prods = $_product->getRelatedProductIds();
foreach($related_prods as $related){
    $_rel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($related);
echo $_rel->getName() . " " . $_rel->getImageUrl(); 
} ?>
```

I am just getting the **url of the image** that I want but **I want to show the image itself**!

Can you suggest of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $related_prods = $_product->getRelatedProductIds(); ?>
<?php foreach($related_prods as $related): ?>
    <?php $_rel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($related); ?>
    <?php echo $_rel->getName(); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $_rel->getImageUrl(); ?>"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In other words: use the HTML `<img>`-tag...

Comment: Thank you very much...it works... Would you reccomend some module to do the slider with the related products instead of this?

Comment: Well that depends completely on the design you are using to build the webshop... In my humble opinion as a programmer, I would display a few products directly, without a slider. But that's just me without the commercial stance ;)